# trying to add a listen live button to my facebook page

Tags: facebook, fbml

I am trying to add a listen live button to my facebook page i have made a picture and have used the code below but where do i add hyperlink code?

```
<img src="my picture link"width="500" height="100" border="0" alt="" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Around the image I imagine?

```
<a href="linkhere"><img src="my picture link"width="500" height="100" border="0" alt="" /></a>
```

Otherwise please add details its very hard to guess your question.

Comment: @AdamGreenwood dont forget to hit that + button if this helps. Also accept the anser if it was the one that helped you. Please read our gaq http://stackoverflow.com/faq